# How to run the django-admin check command?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, environment-variables, python-venv

I just installed Django and am trying to run it for the **first time**.

For now, all I did is `pip3 install Django` and `django-admin startproject`

Right after installing it, I ran `manage.py check` and `django-admin check`. `manage.py check` displayed no issues, but `django-admin check` output was :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting ROOT_URLCONF, but settings are not configured.
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before
accessing settings.
```

I understand I must edit the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable, but

1. What should its value be and when/how was it supposed to be set ?
2. What did I possibly do wrong to get this Error ?

### Update

running `django-admin check --settings=djangotest.settings` solved the `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured` error.

Now I have a new `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangotest'` error. Indeed, `djangotest` is the name of my project. I checked and found the my settings file. It is as follows :

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '########################################' # not the real secret key

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**Why can't django-admin find this file and how do I fix this ?**

Comment: Where are you running the command from? It needs to be somewhere python can locate the `djangotest` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django needs to know where your settings are when it runs commands. When using `manage.py` commands each project sets it's settings path to the `manage.py` file so it knows where to look.

`django-admin` is Django's tool for administrative tasks at a system level, not specific to a given project. Therefore, setting the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` or passing the `settings` option to `django-admin` is generally required when running commands with it.

Therefore it's not that you have done anything wrong with your setup, it's just that `django-admin` doesn't know about a project because it's scope is at system level. Therefore you need to point it in the correct direction of a project in order to run a `check`.

By default `startproject` will have created a `settings.py` file in a module named after the project name you chose.

So based on that you could set an environment variable of `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` with the value `mysite.settings`, for example, where your project looks like;

```
- project
-- manage.py
-- mysite
--- __init__.py
--- settings.py
--- urls.py
--- wsgi.py
```

Alternatively you can pass your settings path to commands, e.g.

```
django-admin check --settings=mysite.settings
python manage.py check --settings=mysite.settings
```

Comment: Indeed, `manage.py` contains all it needs and the `manage.py check` works fine. but I wanted to know why `django-admin check` was giving me an error !

Comment: @AniMir Sorry, missed the focus there. The detail is essentially the same though. Will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I don't have that error anymore, but another one occurred : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangotest'` . `djangotest` is the name of my project indeed. I will update my post !

Comment: @AniMir see my answer for your second problem

Answer (score 4):

`django-admin` is a system tool to manage any django project. By default it doesn't know which one.

If you run `django-admin check` you will get:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
> ROOT_URLCONF, but  settings are not configured. You must either define
> the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
> settings.configure() before accessing settings.

because `django-admin` doesn't know which project settings files to use.

If you run `django-admin check --settings=djangotest.settings` you will get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangotest'

because now django knows what to use but python cannot find a module named `djangotest` on `sys.path`.

You have to add project directory / current directory to the `PYTHONPATH` env variable:

```sh
PYTHONPATH="$(pwd)"
django-admin check --settings=djangotest.settings
```

or specify it as an argument:

```
django-admin check --settings=djangotest.settings --pythonpath=.
```